# bash PHP versus Plesk domain installed PHP

Tags: bash, centos, ssh, php

I have configured my domain to use PHP 5.5.30 ... but when I SSH into the server, bash is telling me that the `php -v` is 5.4.13

Why does bash use a different version of PHP, even though when running .php scripts at the domain level, the version is 5.5.30? Also, `phpinfo()` confirms 5.5.30

Comment: How did you configure your domain?

Comment: The options are all within Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

You configured your php version per domain. The purpose of this is to different php versions on different domains. The shell you get, when you connect to your server does not have the same environment that you configured in your domains.

Comment: So I must just suffer with an older version of PHP when connecting via SSH?

Comment: Yes, it's probably the current version of the your distribution's package. Which dístro is your server running?